# Use not installed EXE\Application in Microsoft Intune Kioskmode

Tags: windows-10, installation, kiosk, intune

I hope you guys have a great Day! I hope someone can help me out :-)

We want to use Intune Kioskmode with an Application that is not "installed" only copied. Unfortunately we can´t install it properly because there is no installer. You need a AUMID (Application User Model ID) from that Application so that you can use the Kisokmode to allow it on the machine.

[image]

That ID seems to be generated when a application is installed. For Win32 Applications it seems to be GUID of well known Folder+Application Name. But as i said the application we use, does not have an installer and is so not know to windows or "installed". So the question is how can i "install" or register the Application so that shows up for example in shell:Appsfolder (run shell:Appsfolder opens a special folder in Windows) and so that the Application gets a AUMID from Windows.

[image]

Thanks a Lot! Carsten

Comment: I think "installed" in this case is a shortcut in the start menu, but I currently cannot verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need an entry in the startmenue to use the AppUserModelId from the Run -> shell:Applicationsfolder in order for the Kiosk to work. You can`t use the direct path as AUMID.

How to get the AUMID: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/configuration/find-the-application-user-model-id-of-an-installed-app

For Example the Path for SAP GUI is C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe. But you have to use {7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe from the shell:AppFolder. The endresult in Intune look like this:

[image]

Comment: This is a horrible answer and is more dialog than answer.  Commenting on a previous comment through an answer IS NOT an answer.  Please re-write this to help people in the future.

Comment: I hope this is better.... :-)

Comment: It’s better but there are far to many grammatical mistakes on common words. The community could make the edits for you but the errors shouldn’t exist.

Comment: Yes.. better.. but as @Ramhound has pointed out... more fixes are in order.